# With increase in equivalent airspeed, what happens to the static stability of an aircraft?

Tags: stability

If we travel faster, does the static stability of an aircraft remain constant?

Comment: Is this another homework question?

Comment: Does [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/98479/64684) answer your question?

Comment: Can you show us the research you have done before asking this question?